# I'm trying 3 different versions of javascript to search Pexels for images, but images do not show up

Tags: javascript, json, search

If anyone can see what is wrong here, please let me know!  Your time and help is appreciated.

```
function displayImage(response) {
    response.photos.forEach((image) => {
        const photoDiv = document.createElement("div");
        photoDiv.innerHTML='<img src=${image.src.large}><figcaption> Photo By: ${image.photographer}</figcaption>';
            document.querySelector(".display_images").appendChild(photoDiv);
    });
}
```

This part of the code outputs the following :

```
<div> Photo By: ${image.photographer}</div><div> Photo By: ${image.photographer}</div>
```

For some reason, the image is ignored as well as the figcaption tag.

There are several sites showing "this is how it's done" and yet the same thing is not woroking for me.

The full javascript is here :

```
// variables
const API_KEY = 'apikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikey';
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const formBtn = document.querySelector(".search_btn");

let page_num=1;
let searchText = "";
let search = false;

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchText=e.target.value;
})

formBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(input.value === ""){
        document.querySelector('.alert').innerHTML = "Empty search! Please enter value..."
        return;
        }
cleargallery();
    search=true;
    SearchPhotos(search_text,page_num);
})

function cleargallery(){
    document.querySelector('.display_images').innerHTML = "";
    page_num=1;
}



// default photos
async function defaultPhotos(page_num) {
    const data = await fetch('https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?page=${page_num}&per_page=24', {
        method: "GET",
        headers:{
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: API_KEY,
        }
    })
    const response = await data.json()
    console.log(response.photos);
    displayImage(response);
}

function displayImage(response) {
    response.photos.forEach((image) => {
        const photoDiv = document.createElement("div");
        photoDiv.innerHTML='<img src=${image.src.large}><figcaption> Photo By: ${image.photographer}</figcaption>';
            document.querySelector(".display_images").appendChild(photoDiv);
    });
}

// search photos
async function SearchPhotos(query, page_num){
    const data=await fetch('https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${query}&page=${page_num}&per_page=24', 
    {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: apikey,
        },
    });
    const response=await data.json();
    console.log(response);

    display_images(response);
}

defaultPhotos(page_num);
```

Comment: You have to use backticks not single quotes, to expand variables inside a string. This is called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)